# =IF() Not working properly in some rows MS EXCEL2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

[image]

Can Someone help me with this formula because some rows are working properly and some rows are not such as this one in the image i shared. its says failed even though m266 and d266 is the same (400.00). I also checked if its in TEXT or NUMBER format

i already tried some troubleshooting like =IF(D266>0,"TRUE","FALSE") and =IF(M266>0,"TRUE","FALSE")

This is the formula:

M266 = =IF(K266-L266+P266=0,"-",K266-L266+P266)

N266 =IF(OR(M266=D266),"Success","Failed")

Comment: You should remove the `OR` from N266 `=IF(OR(M266=D266),"Success","Failed")`.

Comment: Hi Andrew  thanks for your help, i already tried =IF(M5=D5,"Success","Failed") but the result is still the same this is quite confusing

Comment: It could be down to rounding errors with floating-point maths. Does `=IF(ABS(M5 - D5) < 0.01,"Success","Failed")` work?

Comment: This formula shows "Success" to M266 and D266. should i use this? im just new to excel formulas :)

Comment: but it wont show if M266 and d266 is the same

Comment: 1) For using floating-point numbers on computers, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is very informative. It is worthwhile reading it. 2) If a 1 cent possible error is too much, then you could change the `0.01` to, say, `0.0005`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! i would take note of that